# How to convert the angle from float to int

Tags: python

```
size = int(input())
angle = []
clock = []

for i in range(size):
    Inp = input().split(' ')
    clock.append(Inp) 
    hour, minute = int(Inp[0]), int(Inp[1])
    ans = abs((hour * 30 + minute * 0.5) - (minute * 6))
    angle.append(min(360 - ans, ans))   
    
print(*angle,sep="\n")
```

Input:

```
2
5 30
6 00
```

Output:

```
15
180
```

Instead I am getting in float like 15.0  180.0

Comment: If you multiply an int by 0.5 you're going to get a float.

Comment: Did you mean: `minute // 2`?

Comment: That's due to the `* 0.5`

Comment: Did you search for something like "python convert float to int" and not find an answer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is becoming a `float` when you multiply one of your inputs by a float:

```
minute * 0.5
```

One option would be to round it back to an `int` by using `int()` or `floor()`.  However, my approach (assuming rounding down is fine) would be to use int division instead of float multiplication:

```
minute // 2
```